# My JApplet disappears when moved to secondary monitor

Tags: java, swing, graphics, japplet, multiple-monitors

So I wrote a small program for a class. I designed it as a JApplet inside an undecorated JFrame, not in a browser. Other than that, it's a simple drawing program of sorts. You click two points to draw the selected shapes, then it calls a repaint. The problem I'm having is that when you draw while the program has been moved to my secondary monitor, the entire JApplet seems to disappear, only displaying the drawn shape. It only disappears after the 2nd point is selected, so I presume it does this on repaint().

My secondary monitor is using the exact same brand and resolution, even color profile.

Any other technical details, I'm using Java 1.7 (Can't recall which update off the top of my head), Windows 8 Enterprise 64x, using Eclipse's Run button to test.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: *"I designed it as a JApplet inside an undecorated JFrame"*  That is the first thing you should fix.  Make it in a `JPanel` that can then be added to an undecorated frame, a window, or wherever else it is needed.  This problem  sounds suspiciously like the app. is calling `getGraphics()` on a component.  If that is correct, the same effect can be seen when putting another app. in front of the applet, then minimizing the app.  If that is not the case, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for further tips.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try about the JPanel idea, although I also had issues when minimizing the window. The window is undecorated, so I don't have access to the minimize button, so I draw a minimize button that used setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED), and worked well enough, but would not restore the frame properly. Would only show a small bar with the title and buttons on it. Maybe the JPanel will fix that too. Possibly. Anywho, will try, results pending.

Comment: I meant minimize the app. that is in front of your applet!

Comment: Ah, well Imma go out on a limb and sound even more noobish, but putting the JApplet inside a JPanel causes me to see the JVM background, and that's about it. Suspect this is a setLayout() issue of some sort. Quicky dirty FlowLayout() didn't help much.I am indeed calling getGraphics(); in the init() method of the JApplet (Custom class extending JApplet, rather), and had to call init() manually since it doesn't seem to inside a runnable program.

Comment: Did a quick run on the undecorated applet (Moved the JApplet back to the JFrame since it didn't like the JPanel, for now), then started another instance with the decorated frame, and minimizing the decorated one in front of the undecorated one didn't seem to cause any evil mishaps. Also tried 2 undecorated instances and used the JFrame.ICONIFIED minimize method, also didn't mess up the back applet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am indeed calling getGraphics(); in the init() method of the JApplet..

That is the problem.  The `Graphics` object is a transient thing that will be repainted the very next time the JVM thinks there is any need to do so.  That might be triggered by:

- Changing the size or location of the window.
- Covering it with another program and then removing the covering app.
- Adding new components or changing values that are displayed.

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details on how to do what you are attempting to achieve. OTOH Swing has a `JLabel` that can show a `BufferedImage`.  You ***can*** use the `BufferedImage` in the way you want.  When it is updated, call `repaint()` on the label to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Looks like I'm inclined to entirely redesign the program from scratch to fix some of these issues. Would be easier it seems. I've quite misused almost every component I've put into this. Surprised it works in its current state. Java is quite a magical malevolent thing.

Comment: +1 Interesting; a different monitor means different bits for the host peer component.